# Is it possible to make a pure CSS Tree diagram?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, treeview

I've made an attempt [here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/eHQK8/1/). However, it has two problems:

1. IE
2. Last element of a list being a sublist

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below, it's pure CSS and no JS/jQuery (which IMO is way more compatible), works by manipulating borders and spacing.

Works on FF/Chrome & **IE**. Enjoy  :-)

```css
.parent a,

li {

  font-size: 22px;

  color: #000;

  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;

}

.child a,

li {

  font-size: 18px;

  color: #000;

}

.subchild a,

li {

  font-size: 18px;

  color: #888888;

}

.s2child a,

li {

  font-size: 16px;

  color: #ccc;

}

.tree,

.tree ul {

  list-style-type: none;

  margin-left: 0 0 0 10px;

  padding: 0;

  position: relative;

  overflow: hidden;

}

.tree li {

  margin: 0 0 0 15px;

  padding: 0 12px 0 20px;

  position: relative;

}

.tree li::before,

.tree li::after {

  content: '';

  position: absolute;

  left: 0;

}

/* horizontal line on inner list items */

.tree li::before {

  border-top: 2px solid #000;

  top: 14px;

  width: 15px;

  height: 0;

}

/* vertical line on list items */

.tree li:after {

  border-left: 2px solid #000;

  height: 100%;

  width: 0px;

  top: -5px;

}

/* lower line on list items from the first level because they don't have parents */

.tree > li::after {

  top: 15px;

}

/* hide line from the last of the first level list items */

.tree > li:last-child::after {

  display: none;

}

/* hide line from before the Home or starting page or first element */

.tree > li:first-child::before {

  display: none;

}

.tree ul:last-child li:last-child:after {

  height: 20px;

}

.tree a:hover {

  color: red;

  font-weight: 500;

  text-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #F3F3F3;

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Pure CSS Tree</title>
  <link href="tree.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="tree">
    <li class="parent"><a href="#">Grand Parent</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="child"><a href="#">Parent</a>
        </li>
        <li class="child"><a href="#">Parent</a>
          <ul>
            <li class="subchild"><a href="#">Child</a>
              <ul>
                <li class="s2child"><a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li class="s2child"><a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li class="s2child"><a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li class="s2child"><a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li class="last s2child"><a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="subchild"><a href="#">Child</a>
              <ul>
                <li class="s2child"><a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li class="s2child"><a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="child"><a href="#">Parent</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You didn't really go into detail on what your criteria are, but from what you have said, I'd suggest taking a look at [SlickMap CSS](http://astuteo.com/slickmap/).

**Update:** Got it! I just remembered where I'd seen what you're looking for:

[jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/) is a jQuery plugin which creates a tree widget with the kind of styling you want and uses `<ul>` internally to represent it.

Comment: **+1** - Ok, that's **awefully** cool. But it's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a multilevel list, but instead of bullets, there are lines joining parents to children.

Comment: @ssokolow OP is asking for a Pure CSS solution, what you've provided is JS

Comment: @masmrdrr It's been four years but I'm pretty sure that I said "with the kind of styling you want and uses `<ul>` internally to represent it" because I intended him to poke around in jsTree to see how it accomplished the styling in question, not to use jsTree itself.